# Change "Month" text color in CalendarView

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-view, calendarview

I looked into multiple options of setting the textColor through various tags using a custom theme but none of them seem to work. I have attached screenshots for reference. Here's the custom theme I am using for when the theme of the app is Dark.

```
<style name="CalendarWeekDateTextDark" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Button">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorWhite</item>
</style>
```

and I have used it in the XML file as

```
<CalendarView
    android:id="@+id/calendarView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:dateTextAppearance="?attr/CalendarWeekDatTextDark"
    android:weekDayTextAppearance="?attr/CalendarWeekDatTextDark"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottomGuideline"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/endGuideline"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/startGuideline"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/topGuideline" />
```

Screenshots:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having defined following in `styles.xml`:

```
<style name="CustomCalendarMonth" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/orange</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomCalendarDay" parent="TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Caption">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/green</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomCalendarWeek" parent="TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Caption">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/purple</item>
</style>
```

Then in xml:

```
<CalendarView
    android:theme="@style/CustomCalendarMonth"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:dateTextAppearance="@style/CustomCalendarDay"
    android:weekDayTextAppearance="@style/CustomCalendarWeek" />
```

Here will be the output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Helped me clear the bug which was pending for a long time.